# Cannot output image using render()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am trying to output this image :

[image]

However, nothing gets printed out. My code is

```
print render($media_item->field_media_photo['und'][0]
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [image_style_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) instead.

```
$image_uri = $media_item->field_media_photo['und'][0]['uri'];
$image_stylePath = image_style_url("large", $image_uri);
print theme("image", array(
    'path' => $image_stylePath
));
```

Comment: Even better, use [`theme_image_style()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7)

Answer (score 1):

It wont work that way.
Best way is to use theme function.

```
$image = theme('image', $vars);
$path = $media_item->field_media_photo['und'][0]['uri'];

$vars =  array(
  'path' => $path , 
  'alt' => 'alt',
  'attributes' => array('class' => 'example'),
  );
```

here only the path is mandatory.
You can print the variable $image in a .tpl file and the image will appear.